# How can I create a user rating system?

Tags: zend-framework

I have a page `users/index` that contains all users and `users/view/id/5` that shows info for user #5. I want to make some kind of rating for users. That means that a user can click something like `user/rulez/id/5` and give a vote to user #5 and that must be redirected to page `user/index` or `user/view/id/5`, depending on the place he voted.

I've read about `_helper->redirector`, but I still can't think of a method that could take me to the required page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I fully understand your question, but from the action that invokes your voting method, you could simply:

```
$this->_redirect('/user/index');
```

Comment: ok, i think, my explanation is rather complicated.

user can vote on page user/index by clicking "vote" near user's name
user can vote on page user/view/id/5 by clickin "vote".

Both of this ways are handled by user/vote/id/5. It has some logic(updating DB), and than user should be redirected to the page, where he was before (user/index or user/view/id/5). How can i get information, where he was, and add some text like "Tnx for voting"?

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to make the vote via AJAX, while sending in the current URI as a parameter and receive the URI to be redirected to in the AJAX-response.